# How to read a file from a different directory then print it to the screen in c

Tags: c

I am supposed to write a program called www.c. That will read data, describing most popular websites, from a file called web-data, and emit various bits of information about what it found in the file. The info we are supposed to be using is in a file which is in a completley different directory than mine.

How do I open up this file so that I am able to read it?
so far I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
 char* file = "filename";
 int c;
 FILE *www;
 www = fopen("file", "rb");
 if (www) {
    while ((c = getc(www)) != EOF)
    putchar(c);
    fclose(www);
 }
 return 0;
 }
```

but it wont print anything to the screen so I don't think it is actually accessing the file.
Also what command would I use to look through the file and find the best ranked and the lowest alexa?

Thank you so very much for your help.

Comment: Where exactly is it? Your program is looking up a relative path, so you might try `../cs156/pub/web-data` if it's just one level above yours. Or you can do an absolute path: `C:\\Documents and Settings\\ `

Comment: First move back to common parent directory of both your present directory and `cs156` using `..` then browse your file.e.g.: `../../../cs156/pub/web-data`

Comment: The error is staring you in the face.

Comment: Also to debug the program, try printing error message using `perror` function when `www == NULL`

Comment: Is this file exits in the same machine? If yes, use **pwd** command to get the absolute path and use that path in the program. Add debug prints for if(www) { ... } else { printf("fopen failed\n"); }

Comment: I found the absolute path and I used it in the program I also put the perror in it, but it keeps saying "Error: : No such file or directory
" but I know it exists because I can cat it using "cat ~cs156/pub/web-data". So I am extremely confused

Comment: BTW, this sounds like a perfect example where you'd pass the filename as `argv[1]`, instead of hardcoding it in the application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just take the double quotes off 'file' in your `fopen` call:

Like this:

```
 www = fopen(file, "rb");
```

Otherwise you're trying to open a file called "file", rather than a file whose name is referenced by the variable `file`.